# select statement where clause two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem with my select statement at the end. What I want to do is select two levels but im getting no results with this statement. note that if @Level is 1 I don't want to go less than 1 or it might mess up the result so there might be a condition aswell

the part where it goes @Level = @Level -1 I'm having problems with

```
FROM c WHERE c.Level = @Level AND c.Level = @Level - 1 ORDER BY Level ASC
```

or this one

```
FROM c WHERE c.Level BETWEEN @Level AND c.Level - 1 ORDER BY Level ASC
```

SQL

```
DECLARE @Department TABLE
(
Id INT NOT NULL,
Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
ParentId int NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 1, 'Toys', null
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 2, 'Computers', null,  
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 3, 'Consoles', 2
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 4, 'PlayStation 3', 3
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 5, 'Xbox 360', 2
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 6, 'Games', 1
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 7, 'Puzzles', 6
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 8, 'Mens Wear', null
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 9, 'Mens Clothing', 8
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 10, 'Jackets', 9
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 11, 'Shoes', 9
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 12, 'Rain Coats', 10

DECLARE  @Level int = 4
;WITH c AS
(
SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, 1 AS Level
FROM @Department
WHERE ParentId IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId, T.Name, c.Level + 1 AS Level
FROM @Department T
INNER JOIN c on t.ParentId = c.Id   
)
SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, Level

FROM c WHERE c.Level = @Level AND c.Level = @Level - 1 ORDER BY Level ASC

FROM c WHERE c.Level BETWEEN @Level AND @Level - 1 ORDER BY Level ASC
```

Comment: If you're only going one level, you can join this table to itself and put your condition in the on clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `FROM c WHERE c.Level BETWEEN @Level -1 AND @Level ORDER BY Level ASC`

Answer (score 1):

This code here is *NEVER* able to work:

```
@Level = @Level - 1
```

I think you meant to say:

```
c.Level = @Level - 1
```

And even at that... you probably want an `OR` instead of an `AND`.

Think about what you're asking... "give me all the records where the level is 4 and 5 at the same time."

What you mean to say is probably... "give me all the records where the level is 4 OR 5."

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the SQL below, it comes back with 4 rows for level 3 and 1 for level 4:

```
SELECT p.Id as ParentId, 
    p.Name as Parent,
    c.Id, 
    c.Name, 
    c.Level
FROM c as c
left join c p 
on p.Id = c.ParentId
WHERE c.Level = @Level 
ORDER BY p.Name, c.Name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your recursive CTE appears to be right on.  I normally wouldn't put `name` in the CTE (mostly because either the table is only the parent/child fields, or has too many), and join afterwards, but it should still work just fine.

As has been pointed out, your real problem is that your `where` clauses are non-sensical:

- `WHERE c.Level = @Level AND c.Level = @Level - 1` basically asks whether `c.level == c.Level - 1` - which is *always* false.
- `WHERE c.Level BETWEEN @Level AND @Level - 1` is asking for `@Level >= c.Level >= @Level - 1` or `@Level >= @Level - 1` - another impossible condition.

Either one of these approaches should work just fine, if slightly modified:

- `WHERE c.Level = @Level OR c.Level = @Level - 1`
- `WHERE c.Level BETWEEN @Level - 1 AND @Level`

(it doesn't matter if `@Level` is input as `1` - because you *start* at one, there's no lower level for it to report).